# Google Drive - 401 error

Tags: google-drive-api

I've been trying to do the tutorial here https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/java and I keep getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:105)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:287)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
```

The error is at

```
FileList result = service.files().list()
         .setPageSize(10)
         .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
         .execute();
```

Comment: were you able to resolve this?

Comment: yes, it was because of the permissions i had for google drive

Comment: were you trying to Share Files that you had to use permissions which is not indicated in your question?

Comment: were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Yes. I changed DriveScopes.DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY to a scope that gave me full permisions. Can't remember exactly how it was called. I think it was DRIVE, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you might be missing `".credentials/drive-java-quickstart.json"`. As mentioned in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-calendar-api/NsBUa3joEN4) `TokenResponseException: 401 Unauthorized` shows when that's not included.